# Vector spaces "over a field"

Tags: vector-spaces

We often refer to a vector space $V$ "over the field $F$". Every definition I have read defines this as a set of vectors satisfying the axioms, where the scalars in that vector space belong to some field $F$.

What about the elements of the vectors, though? Must those vectors also belong to $F$? Is it possible, for example, for $V$ to be the set of vectors with complex entries (so, the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$) but the scalars be in $\mathbb{R}$? So our vector space would be $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$? Is this a correct use of the definition, or must the entries of the vectors also matter?

Comment: As long as you can multiply the vectors with the scalars (obeying the axioms) you have a vector space. Also, vectors don't "belong" to a field. They do have coordinates (when a basis is given) in a field. Vectors themselves can be functions, polynomials, operators, ..., any collection where the axioms hold. But, yes $\Bbb{C}^n$ is a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$. Its dimension (over $\Bbb{R}$) is $2n$, because you need $2n$ elements to span it all using real scalars only.

Comment: My apologies, I meant to ask whether the elements of the vectors in the vector space must belong to the field. Based on your answer, that does not seem to be the case, provided that the multiplication is permitted. This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: the "elements" of a vector are called components and they are scalars

Comment: One possibility is that the _coordinates_ of an $n$-dimensional vector space belong to the field, in which case you get $\Bbb F^n$.  But there are alot of other possibilities.

Comment: @janmarqz: Does that imply that the components of the vectors also have to belong to $F$ if $V$ is a vector space over $F$?

Comment: What “elements” of the vectors? Vectors can be other objects besides $n$-tuples of scalars. They might for instance, be continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: I think it's worth stressing that there is no definition of "elements of a vector." A vector is an element of a vector space, and the only assumed structure is from the axioms of vector spaces. In general, vectors do not need to look like ordered pairs with entries in some field. They could be functions, for example, as @amd said.

Comment: @JohnP. any vector can be written as a linear combination, where the coefficients are scalars. These scalars are called the components or coordinates of the vector. We never use the word ''elements" for the components

Comment: @janmarqz the components or coordinates of a vector are the entries of a vector IF the vector space is $\Bbb F^n$. Otherwise I can't see why you would call the coefficients "coordinates," except in the particular case that you are writing vectors as a linear sum of basis vectors.

Comment: @ElliotG, ok, but we don't use **linear sum** for a **linear combination**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. It is not uncommon to consider the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ as a two dimensional vector space over the real number $\mathbb{R}$. A basis is given by $1$ and $i$, for example.

All that is needed is that the scalar multiplication is defined in some way. Often this entails that the elements of the vector space are somehow naturally linked to the field over which the space is defined.

However, I can say $\{q,u,i,d\}$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$, with $q+ x  = x $ for each $x \in \{q,u,i,d\}$, further $u+u = i+i = d + d = q$, and $u+i  = d$, $u+d = i$, $i+d = u$. 
Further $\overline{0} x = q$  and $\overline{1} x = x$ for each $x$ in $\{q,u,i,d\}$.

A more natural example is proposed by Rob Arthan: For any set whatsoever $X$ the powerset $\Bbb{P}(X)$  becomes a vector space over $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ if one defines the sum of two sets to be their symmetric difference so that $0 = \emptyset$ and the action of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ in the only possible one: $0A = \emptyset$ and $1A = A$.

Comment: +1: another slightly less ad hoc (or ad hominem $\ddot{\smile}$) example is that the powerset $\Bbb{P}(X)$ of any set $X$ becomes a vector space over $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ if one defines the sum of two sets to be their symmetric difference so that $0 = \emptyset$ and the action of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ in the only possible one: $0A = \emptyset$ and $1A = A$.

Comment: That's a great example in this context.

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

A vector in $\mathbb C^n$ over the field $\mathbb R$ has dimension $2n$ but over the field $\mathbb C$ is just $n$.

This means that the case $\mathbb C^1$ has real dimension $2$ but it has dimension $1$ relative to the complex numbers:

If you give a vector $z_0$ different from $0+0i$ on $\mathbb C^1$ and you have  any other vector $z\in\mathbb C^1$ then 
$$z=\mu z_0$$
where $\mu$ is the complex number $\frac{z}{z_0}$.

Comment: here $z$ has component $\mu$ on the basic $z_0$.